# @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment and @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access rule eslint

Tags: nestjs, typescript-eslint

I try to fix eslint with rule  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
and @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
What should I do to fix it?

This is my code

```js
import fs from "node:fs/promises";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { createTransport, Transporter } from "nodemailer";
import Handlebars from "handlebars";
import { AllConfigType } from "@module/config/config.type";
import { ISendMailOptions } from "./interfaces/send-mail-options.interface";

@Injectable()
export class MailerService {
  private readonly transporter: Transporter;
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService<AllConfigType>) {
    this.transporter = createTransport({
      host: configService.get("mail.host", { infer: true }),
      port: configService.get("mail.port", { infer: true }) || false,
      ignoreTLS: configService.get("mail.ignoreTLS", { infer: true }),
      secure: configService.get("mail.secure", { infer: true }),
      requireTLS: configService.get("mail.requireTLS", {
        infer: true,
      }),
      auth: {
        user: configService.get<string>("mail.user", { infer: true }),
        pass: configService.get<string>("mail.password", { infer: true }),
      },
    });
  }

  async sendMail({
    templatePath,
    context,
    ...mailOptions
  }: ISendMailOptions & {
    templatePath: string;
    context: Record<string, unknown>;
  }): Promise<void> {
    let html: string | undefined;
    if (templatePath && typeof templatePath === "string") {
      const template = await fs.readFile(templatePath, "utf-8");
      html = Handlebars.compile(template, {
        strict: true,
      })(context);
    }
    await this.transporter.sendMail({
      ...mailOptions,
      from: mailOptions.from
        ? mailOptions.from
        : `"${this.configService.get("mail.defaultName", {
            infer: true,
          })}" <${this.configService.get("mail.defaultEmail", {
            infer: true,
          })}>`,
      html: mailOptions.html ? mailOptions.html : html,
    });
  }
}
```

It throw some error

```
27:5   error  Unsafe assignment of an `any` value               @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  27:24  error  Unsafe call of an `any` typed value               @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
  45:11  error  Unsafe member access .sendMail on an `any` value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  45:11  error  Unsafe call of an `any` typed value
```

Comment: Which version of `nodemailer` and `@types/nodemailer` do you use?